# Onclick anchor link only pass one variable but not two variable using ajax

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I would need some advice/assistance here, I have two value to pass to another page but only my product id pass through, my email value is empty in my database. Would appreciate if anyone can assist here. Thanks alot.

```
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

    var httpObject=false;
    if(window.XMLHttpRequest){
        httpObject = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }else if(window.ActiveXObject){
        httpObject = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHttp");
    }

    function ajax_post(id,na){


       var queryString = "?data1=" + id ;
       queryString +=  "&data2=" + na;


        httpObject.onreadystatechange = function(){
            if(httpObject.readyState == 4 && httpObject.status == 200){
                var error = document.getElementById('error');
                var response = httpObject.responseText;

                alert(response);
            }
        }
        httpObject.open("GET", "espaceproductinsert.php"+queryString ,true);
        httpObject.send(null);
     }

     </script>
```

Page 1

```
     <?php

     $sql = mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM espaceproduct WHERE email = 'jaychou@hotmail.com' ");

     $row = mysql_fetch_array($sql);

     $id = $row['id'];
     echo $email = $row['email'];

     echo '<a  href="#" onClick="ajax_post('.$id.','.$email.')" >'. $id .'</a>'."<br/>";

     ?>
```

Both value should be insert in espaceproductinsert.php

```
      $csg = $_GET['data1'];
      $add = $_GET['data2'];

      $sql2 = mysql_query ("INSERT INTO espaceproduct (storename,productname) VALUES ('$csg','$add') ");
```

Answer (score 0):

It's `onclick` not `onClick` in your line:

```
echo '<a  href="#" onClick="ajax_post('.$id.','.$email.')" >'. $id .'</a>'."<br/>";
```

See if that clears it up.

Answer (score 0):

I think code sequence in ajax_post function is not correct, you should change sequence like this

```
    httpObject.open("GET", "espaceproductinsert.php"+queryString ,true);

    httpObject.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(httpObject.readyState == 4 && httpObject.status == 200){
            var error = document.getElementById('error');
            var response = httpObject.responseText;

            alert(response);
        }
    }
    httpObject.send(null);
```

make this change and check